# Issue with Codeplex ADUI Object Picker after build

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory

I'm trying to use the [Active Directory Object Picker from Codeplex](http://adui.codeplex.com/) to open the users & groups dialog box.

It is working great if running during debug mode from VS2010, but when running the release of the solution, after 2 or 3 times opening the dialog box, it opens but non of the buttons are responding to clicks (you can see they are pressed but don't activate anything). Nothing at all. its not stuck. its just not responding to any of the clicks on any button. the only way to close it is to kill the process from task manager.

I've created and running the solution on a Win7 x64 machine using C# VS2010.
The build is Any CPU.

```
DirectoryObjectPickerDialog picker = new DirectoryObjectPickerDialog();
picker.AllowedObjectTypes = ObjectTypes.Computers;
picker.DefaultObjectTypes = ObjectTypes.Computers;
picker.AllowedLocations = Locations.GlobalCatalog;
picker.DefaultLocations = Locations.GlobalCatalog;
picker.MultiSelect = true;
DialogResult dialogResult = picker.ShowDialog();
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
{
    DirectoryObject[] results;
    results = picker.SelectedObjects;
    if (results == null)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i <= results.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        ListViewItem theItem = new ListViewItem(results[i].Name);
        LvServersNames.Items.Add(theItem);
    }

    LblTotalServers.Text = "Server(s) : " + results.Length.ToString();
}

picker.Dispose();
picker = null;
```

Comment: do you have code sample that you are using..??

Comment: http://update.eprocsolutions.com/rc30.rar - this file is the project based on this code. no issue when running it during debug but as release it can sometimes stuck. When this code is used in a larger project it will stuck when running the release.

Comment: what code do you have I would not recommend posting a .rar or .zip file download doesn't guarantee the safeness of the file.. what code have  you tried thus far

Comment: basically, this code is based on the one I've downloaded form http://adui.codeplex.com. by itself, its working fine, but as part of a lager project I'll have an issue.

Comment: Well post the part of the code that has the issue.. we could care less about the download we only care about helping.. so what you post is not copy written code.. make sense..?

Comment: this is the part calling the object picker dialog box. Its working and its opening the dialog. no problem on debug. dialog not responding during release

Comment: When you say not working what do you mean..? also look at how you declare results you are not Releasing that object what if you were to change it to be results = new DirectoryObject[]; is there a dll namespace copying / path issue..? are you getting errors.. would like to know more information. also make sure that picker truly implements IDisposable as well

Answer (score 0):

[BOITE DE DIALOGUE D'OBJET - DIRECTORY OBJECT PICKER](http://www.csharpfr.com//code.aspx?ID=52023) it's in french, but it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the discussions section on Codeplex. There's a question specifically about running the code on x64, basically you have to make a few hacks as per the instructions, but it works OK. See:

http://adui.codeplex.com/discussions/38047?ProjectName=adui

A word of warning though - if you need to return the SID of the selected object(s), you'll probably then get as far as I got with the dialog before giving up. On certain operating systems, a bug with one of the interfaces means that it's impossible to marshal the data back to .NET if you specify extended attributes (which you have to in order to get SIDs). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676013(v=vs.85).aspx